# Changing the writing direction in browser apps (firefox, uc browser)

Tags: keyboard, browser, languages

I write in Arabic most of the time, which unlike English you start writing from the right. Now in browsers writing in Arabic in text boxes starts from the left and the text crawls from left to write which is really annoying especially when editing what I wrote. Is there any way to inverse the direction when writing in Arabic?

Comment: Do you have control over the web pages those text boxes are in – or does the browser you use support "user styles"? In the latter case the easiest way would be applying a user-style like `* input, * textarea { text-align:right !important }`. That would put the cursor at the right place (oops). And yes, I've just tested that :)

Comment: @Izzy unfortunately I don't have control over the web pages, do you know how can I change this user style thing in UC browser or firefox?

Comment: No idea about UC. For Firefox there's the *Stylish* enxtension (at least for the desktop version) which can do that – but I'm not sure whether it is available for Firefox on Android as well. According to [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/stylish/) it should be.

Comment: I was thinking the 'Force RTL layout' in the developer settings

Answer (score 0):

Basically its due to language you have chosen and the **predication search** as you type.  You need to off the predication search from the uc browser setting after that you can write from right to left you can check update from ucmini.co.in for more information about language and setting option.